# Unrecognized selector sent to instance on ios tutorial

Tags: ios

(I know that this question has been asked many times but they didn't solve my problem)

Hello, I am following the IOS getting started tutorial on its website and I did everything as described but I get a weird exception. I don't know why. I am also new to IOS environment and swift (this is my first mac using and I got it two days ago.).

Here is my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameTextField: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    // MARK: Actions
    @IBAction func setDefaultMealNameLabel(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Meal Name"
    }

}
```

It should change the `mealNameLabel`'s text to "Default Meal Name". How ever I get the weird exception in the title. I also don't know what a selector is, I am just getting started.

EDIT:
Parameter type to fuction named `setDefaultMealNameLabel` was UIButton before. It both didn' work.

EDIT:
Where the error occured:

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { // DEBUGGER SHOWS THAT, IN THIS PLACE, ERROR OCURED.

    var window: UIWindow?


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

}

Comment: On which line of code is the error?

Comment: check ibaction in storyboard . if any bad connection exist then remove it .

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed please see the edit.

Comment: @KKRocks I have already done it. But there is no bad connection.

Comment: can you add exception message ?

Comment: and when exception caused ?

Comment: @KKRocks I am sorry. I have been looking at the wrong place. There was a bad connection. I have removed other connections that doesn't exists and wroked. Please post and answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to check in your storyboard, If any bad **IBAction** and **IBOutlet** exist then remove that.

Hope it will helping you .

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that you have changed the name of the IBAction *after* you made the connection from storyboard? In that case, when you are tapping the button it's trying to call a method that doesn't exist anymore.

If this is the case you need to remove the connected action and update it on the button's sent events in storyboard.

[**Example**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zquSO.png)

[**Selectors in Swift**](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/what-is-a-selector)

Comment: This was the case before, when it gave me exceptions about label and text field. But for the button, I forgot to look at the actions tab, I was looking at the outlets. Thanks for the answer anyway.